# Active Directory authentication on WSS 3.0

Tags: sharepoint, authentication, active-directory, wss

Our customer wants to use their existing active directory to authenticate users on a new WSS 3.0 server. The company is using several domains.

I have read this thread [sharepoint-wss-authentication-across-multiple-domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766904/sharepoint-wss-authentication-across-multiple-domains) but it does not give me the information on how to set up the sync-connection. Ive seen on meny places that AD sync is only available in MOSS 2007, but is this true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For authentication, you won't have a problem as long as the domains are all trusted - basically if the windows server will accept a login from that domain, sharepoint will work with it also.

For profile information, the out of box import goes into mysites, which is a MOSS only feature. However, there is no reason you can't write your own code to pull data from AD to WSS user profiles.

Comment: Thank you Tom! That was the answer I was looking for.

The confusion is big around SharePoint. I have found meny convergating facts regarding the features in MOSS vs WSS on the the net.